# clear example of using PHPSpec with Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpspec

I've scoured the net and cannot find a clear example of using PHPSpec with Laravel for specifying the behaviour of Models. I've watched the [Jeffrey Way video on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/lessons/phpspec-laravel-and-refactoring), which shows how to test other classes within a Laravel project but not Models.

Examples I've found seem to differ slightly. I guess as this is still fairly new territory its not well documented. I've used Codeception for functional testing but wish to start a new project with solid unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you should use phpunit rather that phpspec. phpspec is quite superior, but is quite a new tool with very little documentation. Work with PHPUnit for unit testing and then move in when you feel comfortable with TDD,

Comment: Your preaching is not helpful and does not actually answer the question.